# Export artifact and forcefully replace existing file while another process is using it

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

When moving onto IntelliJ, one feature I missed from Eclipse is its ability to export and replace a jar even if that jar is being used by another process.

When working on plugins with an API, this feature was very useful as I could make a change in Eclipse, export and do a simple reload command allowing me to instantly see my changes.

However, in IntelliJ, it complains the jar is being used by another process. This forces me to stop the process, replace the jar and start it again which takes a very long time.

Is there a plugin or a setting I could change in IntelliJ which could bring back this feature?

I've looked around on Google but haven't found anything relating to this feature in Eclipse working in IntelliJ.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check  `idea.jars.nocopy` option in the bin/idea.properties file.

Try to uncomment it and set explicitly `idea.jars.nocopy=false`

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# IDEA can copy library .jar files to prevent their locking.
# By default this behavior is enabled on Windows and disabled on other platforms.
# Uncomment this property to override.
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# idea.jars.nocopy=false
```